# Proper way to invoke jQuery UI menu widget

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm trying to theme a menu using the jQuery UI menu widget.

Here is what I've added in my template-preprocess.php inside the preprocess_page hook:

`drupal_add_js('(function ($) { jQuery(document).ready(function () { jQuery( "#test-menu-id" ).menu(); }); }(jQuery));', 'inline');`

I'm using jQuery Update to set my jQuery version, and according to the status report it is:

jQuery 1.8.3
jQuery UI 1.10.2

However, whenever I load the page to test I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).menu is not a function`

According to http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/ the menu widget was added in version 1.9.

If I manually add the external JS file from https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js, then it works (though this is obviously not the appropriate solution).

Can any one share any insight into why this would be happening, or provide any advice?

Thanks,
Pablo